# Failing to connect to an authenticated WFS using owslib.wfs.WebFeatureService

Tags: python, wfs, owslib

Does anyone know why the following code isn't working? Substituting the exact same code works for the WMS at the same URL, so not sure what pyproj has to do with it (see traceback below).

I can access an authenticated WFS in QGIS, but connecting through owslib fails. I can access an unrelated and unauthenticated WFS using this code.

I intentionally haven't included the username and password for this post.

```
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService
bom_wfs = WebFeatureService(url="https://spatial.bom.gov.au/cgi-bin/mapserver/users/username/wxs?", username="username", password="password", version="1.0.0")
print(bom_wfs.identification.title)
```

The traceback error code I get is:

```
 C:\Users\jmckechn\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\python.exe C:/Users/jmckechn/PycharmProjects/TreeProject/wfs_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jmckechn/PycharmProjects/TreeProject/wfs_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    bom_wfs = WebFeatureService(url="https://spatial.bom.gov.au/cgi-bin/mapserver/users/username/wxs?", username="username", password="password", version="1.0.0")
  File "C:\Users\jmckechn\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\owslib\wfs.py", line 50, in WebFeatureService
    timeout=timeout, headers=headers, auth=auth)
  File "C:\Users\jmckechn\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\owslib\feature\wfs100.py", line 104, in __new__
    auth=auth,
  File "C:\Users\jmckechn\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\owslib\feature\wfs100.py", line 144, in __init__
    self._buildMetadata(parse_remote_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\jmckechn\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\owslib\feature\wfs100.py", line 171, in _buildMetadata
    feature, featuretypelist, parse_remote_metadata, auth=self.auth
  File "C:\Users\jmckechn\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\owslib\feature\wfs100.py", line 398, in __init__
    wgs84 = pyproj.Proj("epsg:4326")
  File "C:\Users\jmckechn\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pyproj\proj.py", line 295, in __init__
    self.crs = CRS.from_user_input(projparams if projparams is not None else kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jmckechn\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs.py", line 226, in from_user_input
    return cls.from_string(value)
  File "C:\Users\jmckechn\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs.py", line 189, in from_string
    return cls.from_epsg(val)
  File "C:\Users\jmckechn\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs.py", line 167, in from_epsg
    return cls("epsg:{}".format(code))
  File "C:\Users\jmckechn\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs.py", line 146, in __init__
    super(CRS, self).__init__(projstring)
  File "pyproj/_crs.pyx", line 307, in pyproj._crs._CRS.__init__
  File "C:\Users\jmckechn\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pyproj\datadir.py", line 62, in get_data_dir
    "Valid PROJ.4 data directory not found."
pyproj.exceptions.DataDirError: Valid PROJ.4 data directory not found.Either set the path using the environmental variable PROJ_LIB or with `pyproj.datadir.set_data_dir`.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `pyproj` correctly for WFS to work correctly - a quick check of the [referenced line](https://github.com/geopython/OWSLib/blob/master/owslib/feature/wfs100.py#L398) shows it is trying to create a projection (epsg:4326) there.

So as the error message says:

```
Valid PROJ.4 data directory not found.Either set the path using the environmental variable PROJ_LIB or with `pyproj.datadir.set_data_dir`.
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. Even after you've pointed that out I'm struggling to interpret the lines.

I'm using an ArcGIS Pro python installation, and tried conda install pyproj which didn't make a difference. I read on a similar post that changing the pyproj version may help - and I'm now getting a different (authorisation) error... not sure if it has solved the projection issue. Am I on the right track or is there a different way of fixing the data directory?